# Can a node sign over a transaction without the state cordapp?

Tags: corda

A regulator node is needed to sign over a transaction containing a few linear states of type X, Y. Can the regulator sign the transaction without the `state/contract` cordapp? The node still have the `flow-cordapps` with the flows.

Will there be any issue in deserialisation? The regulator does need to store the states, but he just need to sign the transaction.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible, but not for the reasons `manish` described above.

As of Corda 3, sending the transaction to the regulator to be signed will result in a `java.io.NotSerializableException`.

This behaviour makes sense - what is the purpose of signing over a transaction where you cannot see the input and output states? If you do want to provide a signature regardless, you could work around it by sending a `FilteredTransaction` where all the states have been filtered out, along with any other components the regulator doesn't have the class definitions for. Then use `serviceHub.createSignatures(filteredTransaction)`.

NB Here is an example of the stacktrace I received when I attempted to send a counterparty a `SignedTransaction` with components for which they did not have the class definitions:

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: Unexpected throwable: net.corda.core.transactions.WireTransaction -> net.corda.core.transactions.WireTransaction -> null java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: net.corda.core.transactions.WireTransaction -> net.corda.core.transactions.WireTransaction -> null
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.amqp.ObjectSerializer.construct(ObjectSerializer.kt:138)
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.amqp.ObjectSerializer.readObjectBuildViaConstructor(ObjectSerializer.kt:97)
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.amqp.ObjectSerializer.readObject(ObjectSerializer.kt:82)
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.amqp.DeserializationInput.readObject$node_api(DeserializationInput.kt:135)
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.amqp.DeserializationInput.readObjectOrNull$node_api(DeserializationInput.kt:109)
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.amqp.DeserializationInput.readObjectOrNull$node_api$default(DeserializationInput.kt:108)
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.amqp.DeserializationInput$deserialize$1.invoke(DeserializationInput.kt:98)
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.amqp.DeserializationInput.des(DeserializationInput.kt:80)
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.amqp.DeserializationInput.deserialize(DeserializationInput.kt:96)
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.amqp.AbstractAMQPSerializationScheme.deserialize(AMQPSerializationScheme.kt:123)
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.SerializationFactoryImpl$deserialize$1$1.invoke(SerializationScheme.kt:111)
    at net.corda.core.serialization.SerializationFactory.withCurrentContext(SerializationAPI.kt:66)
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.SerializationFactoryImpl$deserialize$1.invoke(SerializationScheme.kt:111)
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.SerializationFactoryImpl$deserialize$1.invoke(SerializationScheme.kt:86)
    at net.corda.core.serialization.SerializationFactory.asCurrent(SerializationAPI.kt:80)
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.SerializationFactoryImpl.deserialize(SerializationScheme.kt:111)
    at net.corda.core.transactions.SignedTransaction.getCoreTransaction(SignedTransaction.kt:273)
    at net.corda.core.transactions.SignedTransaction.getId(SignedTransaction.kt:55)
    at net.corda.core.node.ServiceHub$DefaultImpls.createSignature(ServiceHub.kt:264)
    at net.corda.core.node.ServiceHub$DefaultImpls.createSignature(ServiceHub.kt:279)
    at net.corda.node.services.api.ServiceHubInternal$DefaultImpls.createSignature(ServiceHubInternal.kt)
    at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode$ServiceHubInternalImpl.createSignature(AbstractNode.kt:820)
    at net.corda.core.node.ServiceHub$DefaultImpls.addSignature(ServiceHub.kt:302)
    at net.corda.node.services.api.ServiceHubInternal$DefaultImpls.addSignature(ServiceHubInternal.kt)
    at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode$ServiceHubInternalImpl.addSignature(AbstractNode.kt:820)
    at net.corda.core.node.ServiceHub$DefaultImpls.addSignature(ServiceHub.kt:311)
    at net.corda.node.services.api.ServiceHubInternal$DefaultImpls.addSignature(ServiceHubInternal.kt)
    at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode$ServiceHubInternalImpl.addSignature(AbstractNode.kt:820)
    at com.template.Responder.call(App.kt:58)
    at com.template.Responder.call(App.kt:54)
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.run(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:96)
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.run(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:44)
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber.run1(Fiber.java:1092)
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber.exec(Fiber.java:788)
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.RunnableFiberTask.doExec(RunnableFiberTask.java:100)
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.RunnableFiberTask.run(RunnableFiberTask.java:91)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at net.corda.node.utilities.AffinityExecutor$ServiceAffinityExecutor$1$thread$1.run(AffinityExecutor.kt:62)
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Malformed transaction, OUTPUTS_GROUP at index 0 cannot be deserialised
    at net.corda.core.transactions.TraversableTransaction.deserialiseComponentGroup(MerkleTransaction.kt:70)
    at net.corda.core.transactions.TraversableTransaction.<init>(MerkleTransaction.kt:25)
    at net.corda.core.transactions.WireTransaction.<init>(WireTransaction.kt:43)
    ... 47 more
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: Unexpected throwable: Interface net.corda.core.contracts.ContractState requires a field named participants but that isn't found in the schema or any superclass schemas net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.carpenter.InterfaceMismatchException: Interface net.corda.core.contracts.ContractState requires a field named participants but that isn't found in the schema or any superclass schemas
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.carpenter.ClassCarpenter.validateSchema(ClassCarpenter.kt:434)
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.carpenter.ClassCarpenter.build(ClassCarpenter.kt:106)
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.carpenter.MetaCarpenterBase.step(MetaCarpenter.kt:69)
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.carpenter.MetaCarpenter.build(MetaCarpenter.kt:98)
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.amqp.SerializerFactory.processSchema(SerializerFactory.kt:235)
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.amqp.SerializerFactory.processSchema$default(SerializerFactory.kt:216)
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.amqp.SerializerFactory$get$1.invoke(SerializerFactory.kt:185)
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.amqp.SerializerFactory$get$1.invoke(SerializerFactory.kt:40)
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.amqp.SerializerFactory.get(SerializerFactory.kt:184)
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.amqp.DeserializationInput.readObject$node_api(DeserializationInput.kt:131)
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.amqp.DeserializationInput.readObjectOrNull$node_api(DeserializationInput.kt:109)
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.amqp.DeserializationInput.readObjectOrNull$node_api$default(DeserializationInput.kt:108)
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.amqp.DeserializationInput$deserialize$1.invoke(DeserializationInput.kt:98)
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.amqp.DeserializationInput.des(DeserializationInput.kt:80)
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.amqp.DeserializationInput.deserialize(DeserializationInput.kt:96)
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.amqp.AbstractAMQPSerializationScheme.deserialize(AMQPSerializationScheme.kt:123)
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.SerializationFactoryImpl$deserialize$1$1.invoke(SerializationScheme.kt:111)
    at net.corda.core.serialization.SerializationFactory.withCurrentContext(SerializationAPI.kt:66)
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.SerializationFactoryImpl$deserialize$1.invoke(SerializationScheme.kt:111)
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.SerializationFactoryImpl$deserialize$1.invoke(SerializationScheme.kt:86)
    at net.corda.core.serialization.SerializationFactory.asCurrent(SerializationAPI.kt:80)
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.SerializationFactoryImpl.deserialize(SerializationScheme.kt:111)
    at net.corda.core.transactions.TraversableTransaction$outputs$1.invoke(MerkleTransaction.kt:357)
    at net.corda.core.transactions.TraversableTransaction$outputs$1.invoke(MerkleTransaction.kt:18)
    at net.corda.core.transactions.TraversableTransaction.deserialiseComponentGroup(MerkleTransaction.kt:66)
    at net.corda.core.transactions.TraversableTransaction.<init>(MerkleTransaction.kt:25)
    at net.corda.core.transactions.WireTransaction.<init>(WireTransaction.kt:43)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.amqp.ObjectSerializer.construct(ObjectSerializer.kt:138)
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.amqp.ObjectSerializer.readObjectBuildViaConstructor(ObjectSerializer.kt:97)
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.amqp.ObjectSerializer.readObject(ObjectSerializer.kt:82)
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.amqp.DeserializationInput.readObject$node_api(DeserializationInput.kt:135)
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.amqp.DeserializationInput.readObjectOrNull$node_api(DeserializationInput.kt:109)
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.amqp.DeserializationInput.readObjectOrNull$node_api$default(DeserializationInput.kt:108)
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.amqp.DeserializationInput$deserialize$1.invoke(DeserializationInput.kt:98)
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.amqp.DeserializationInput.des(DeserializationInput.kt:80)
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.amqp.DeserializationInput.deserialize(DeserializationInput.kt:96)
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.amqp.AbstractAMQPSerializationScheme.deserialize(AMQPSerializationScheme.kt:123)
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.SerializationFactoryImpl$deserialize$1$1.invoke(SerializationScheme.kt:111)
    at net.corda.core.serialization.SerializationFactory.withCurrentContext(SerializationAPI.kt:66)
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.SerializationFactoryImpl$deserialize$1.invoke(SerializationScheme.kt:111)
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.SerializationFactoryImpl$deserialize$1.invoke(SerializationScheme.kt:86)
    at net.corda.core.serialization.SerializationFactory.asCurrent(SerializationAPI.kt:80)
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.SerializationFactoryImpl.deserialize(SerializationScheme.kt:111)
    at net.corda.core.transactions.SignedTransaction.getCoreTransaction(SignedTransaction.kt:273)
    at net.corda.core.transactions.SignedTransaction.getId(SignedTransaction.kt:55)
    at net.corda.core.node.ServiceHub$DefaultImpls.createSignature(ServiceHub.kt:264)
    at net.corda.core.node.ServiceHub$DefaultImpls.createSignature(ServiceHub.kt:279)
    at net.corda.node.services.api.ServiceHubInternal$DefaultImpls.createSignature(ServiceHubInternal.kt)
    at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode$ServiceHubInternalImpl.createSignature(AbstractNode.kt:820)
    at net.corda.core.node.ServiceHub$DefaultImpls.addSignature(ServiceHub.kt:302)
    at net.corda.node.services.api.ServiceHubInternal$DefaultImpls.addSignature(ServiceHubInternal.kt)
    at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode$ServiceHubInternalImpl.addSignature(AbstractNode.kt:820)
    at net.corda.core.node.ServiceHub$DefaultImpls.addSignature(ServiceHub.kt:311)
    at net.corda.node.services.api.ServiceHubInternal$DefaultImpls.addSignature(ServiceHubInternal.kt)
    at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode$ServiceHubInternalImpl.addSignature(AbstractNode.kt:820)
    at com.template.Responder.call(App.kt:58)
    at com.template.Responder.call(App.kt:54)
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.run(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:96)
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.run(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:44)
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber.run1(Fiber.java:1092)
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber.exec(Fiber.java:788)
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.RunnableFiberTask.doExec(RunnableFiberTask.java:100)
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.RunnableFiberTask.run(RunnableFiberTask.java:91)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at net.corda.node.utilities.AffinityExecutor$ServiceAffinityExecutor$1$thread$1.run(AffinityExecutor.kt:62)

    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.amqp.DeserializationInput.des(DeserializationInput.kt:84)
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.amqp.DeserializationInput.deserialize(DeserializationInput.kt:96)
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.amqp.AbstractAMQPSerializationScheme.deserialize(AMQPSerializationScheme.kt:123)
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.SerializationFactoryImpl$deserialize$1$1.invoke(SerializationScheme.kt:111)
    at net.corda.core.serialization.SerializationFactory.withCurrentContext(SerializationAPI.kt:66)
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.SerializationFactoryImpl$deserialize$1.invoke(SerializationScheme.kt:111)
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.SerializationFactoryImpl$deserialize$1.invoke(SerializationScheme.kt:86)
    at net.corda.core.serialization.SerializationFactory.asCurrent(SerializationAPI.kt:80)
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.SerializationFactoryImpl.deserialize(SerializationScheme.kt:111)
    at net.corda.core.transactions.TraversableTransaction$outputs$1.invoke(MerkleTransaction.kt:357)
    at net.corda.core.transactions.TraversableTransaction$outputs$1.invoke(MerkleTransaction.kt:18)
    at net.corda.core.transactions.TraversableTransaction.deserialiseComponentGroup(MerkleTransaction.kt:66)
    ... 49 more

    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.amqp.DeserializationInput.des(DeserializationInput.kt:84) ~[corda-node-api-3.2-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.amqp.DeserializationInput.deserialize(DeserializationInput.kt:96) ~[corda-node-api-3.2-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.amqp.AbstractAMQPSerializationScheme.deserialize(AMQPSerializationScheme.kt:123) ~[corda-node-api-3.2-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.SerializationFactoryImpl$deserialize$1$1.invoke(SerializationScheme.kt:111) ~[corda-node-api-3.2-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.serialization.SerializationFactory.withCurrentContext(SerializationAPI.kt:66) ~[corda-core-3.2-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.SerializationFactoryImpl$deserialize$1.invoke(SerializationScheme.kt:111) ~[corda-node-api-3.2-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.SerializationFactoryImpl$deserialize$1.invoke(SerializationScheme.kt:86) ~[corda-node-api-3.2-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.serialization.SerializationFactory.asCurrent(SerializationAPI.kt:80) ~[corda-core-3.2-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.SerializationFactoryImpl.deserialize(SerializationScheme.kt:111) ~[corda-node-api-3.2-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.transactions.SignedTransaction.getCoreTransaction(SignedTransaction.kt:273) ~[corda-core-3.2-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.transactions.SignedTransaction.getId(SignedTransaction.kt:55) ~[corda-core-3.2-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.node.ServiceHub$DefaultImpls.createSignature(ServiceHub.kt:264) ~[corda-core-3.2-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.node.ServiceHub$DefaultImpls.createSignature(ServiceHub.kt:279) ~[corda-core-3.2-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.api.ServiceHubInternal$DefaultImpls.createSignature(ServiceHubInternal.kt) ~[corda-node-3.2-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode$ServiceHubInternalImpl.createSignature(AbstractNode.kt:820) ~[corda-node-3.2-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.node.ServiceHub$DefaultImpls.addSignature(ServiceHub.kt:302) ~[corda-core-3.2-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.api.ServiceHubInternal$DefaultImpls.addSignature(ServiceHubInternal.kt) ~[corda-node-3.2-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode$ServiceHubInternalImpl.addSignature(AbstractNode.kt:820) ~[corda-node-3.2-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.node.ServiceHub$DefaultImpls.addSignature(ServiceHub.kt:311) ~[corda-core-3.2-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.api.ServiceHubInternal$DefaultImpls.addSignature(ServiceHubInternal.kt) ~[corda-node-3.2-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode$ServiceHubInternalImpl.addSignature(AbstractNode.kt:820) ~[corda-node-3.2-corda.jar:?]
    at com.template.Responder.call(App.kt:58) ~[cordapp-0.1.jar:?]
    at com.template.Responder.call(App.kt:54) ~[cordapp-0.1.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.run(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:96) [corda-node-3.2-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.run(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:44) [corda-node-3.2-corda.jar:?]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber.run1(Fiber.java:1092) [quasar-core-0.7.9-jdk8.jar:0.7.9]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber.exec(Fiber.java:788) [quasar-core-0.7.9-jdk8.jar:0.7.9]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.RunnableFiberTask.doExec(RunnableFiberTask.java:100) [quasar-core-0.7.9-jdk8.jar:0.7.9]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.RunnableFiberTask.run(RunnableFiberTask.java:91) [quasar-core-0.7.9-jdk8.jar:0.7.9]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_171]
    at net.corda.node.utilities.AffinityExecutor$ServiceAffinityExecutor$1$thread$1.run(AffinityExecutor.kt:62) [corda-node-3.2-corda.jar:?]
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible .
CollectSignaturesFlow required the counter party to override the SendTransactionFlow to collect the signature.This could be only possible only the node has the cordapp that has the **initated by** flow.

Comment: I'm actually splitting the cordapp to state-contract-cordapps and flow-cordapp, so the node still have the flow-cordapp to be able to respond to the flow. In my case, I'm saying the node don't have the state-contract cordapp consisting of the states/contracts only.